# Why is i incremented one more time after a simple for loop?

Tags: javascript

In case I run the following loop and (intentionally) use var in my assignment of i, why is i equal to 4 and not 3 in the outer scope of the for-loop? Why and when does the final increment happen?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) console.log(i);
console.log(i)
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
3
4 //<- outer console.log
```

Comment: Variables declared with the `var` keyword are scoped to the surrounding function, or to the global scope if there is none. `i` was incremented to `4`, did not pass the for loop's condition, and your last console.log was executed then

Comment: It has to be > 3 to get out of the loop, and it isn't scoped to the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***i*** is 4 when the condition `i <= 3` fails (hence the for loop stops) and you console.log 4.

take a look at the flow chart:

[image: js for loop flow chart]

Let's start a verbose description of the loop from the last iteration (when ***i*** is 3):

1. block is going to execute the console.log(3)
2. ***i*** is incremented by 1 so now ***i*** is 4
3. Check is ***i*** (aka 4) smaller or equal than 3?
   No, it's not. The loop stops.
4. Next line simply console.log(4);

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared with var are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same scope the for loop is in.

Answer (score 0):

Total number of iterations that happen in your loop are 4. Starting from 0.

As soon as `i` becomes `4` in the 4th iteration because of `i++` and this condition fails:

```
i<=3;
```

That's why you get `4` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop consists of three things
`for (var i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++)`

In the first part (before the semi-colon), you're creating a new variable.
In the second part, you declare a condition against which the for-loop is checked.

In the third part, you increment the variable by 1.
The way a for-loop works, is that it reads the variable (first check i = 0). Then it checks if i <= 3 (which in the first run is `true`).

Then it executes the code between the brackets {} of the for-loop.
Rinse and repeat. The for-loop keeps running for as long as your condition holds true.

As to the `++` operator, it will first read your variable 'as-is' and then increment that same variable. In doubt, go through the [basics](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Looping/Increment.htm#:%7E:text=Adding%201%20to%20a%20variable,variables%20and%20not%20on%20literals.)